# Oracle-DB: Reliable way to calculate the length of a field in CHAR from all_tab_columns.data_length?

Tags: oracle, encoding, varchar2

I've written a very simple database access layer that maps C# objects onto database tables and back. It uses the information in all_tab_columns in order to do some input validation (mainly length checking). It works ok on ISO-encoded databases but on UTF-8 it produces wrong results. I tried (data_length / LENGTHB('ä')) which sometimes seems to work and sometimes doesn't. I'm aware it's a dirty hack, but I haven't found a pattern yet. Is there a reliable way to calculate the CHAR length of a VARCHAR2 field from data_length?

Comment: `DECODE(
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM nls_database_parameters
           WHERE UPPER(parameter) = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
             AND UPPER(value) LIKE '%UTF8%'),
         1, (data_length / 2),
         data_length)`

Does what I need but it isn't generic. It wouldn't work on a UTF-16 database.

Comment: Don't UTF-8 characters vary in size from 1-4 bytes? That seems impossible to infer without looking at the actual data in the column, unless you just want an estimated range of character lengths.

Comment: They do. Actually I'm trying to get the size that was provided when the table was created. E.g. if the column is defined as `col1 VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)` I'd like to get the 64. ALL_TAB_COLUMNS gives me 128 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. ALL_TAB_COLUMNS provides a field CHAR_LENGTH that contains the maximum amount of characters in the column. Example:

```
SELECT column_name, char_length FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'SOME_TABLE';
```